# Extremely slow wifi and disconnection issues on Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, xubuntu, internet

I dual booted xubuntu latest version with win 10 but for some reason wifi on win 10 works fine and on Linux it keeps fluctuating and disconnects most of the time. Also when I used the Tru Ubuntu option during installation I was getting full wifi signal and good speed so I'm very confused at how to solve this issue?

I've disabled ipv6 , changed power conf to 2 and still I'm getting the same issue.

> ```
> > sudo lshw -c network
> ```

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 30
   serial: e8:2a:44:e3:9a:ff
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.18.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.>
   resources: irq:123 memory:91000000-911fffff
```

> sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware

```
[    0.155462] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.298729] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[   14.722678] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 42e41877
[   16.999673] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x300 build 0x3e8, firmware rome 0x300 build 0x111
[   18.862052] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `sudo lshw -c network` also `sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Comment: i have edited the question.Sorry for the late reply but my xubuntu is really struggling to connect to wifi rn.